# How do I stop Mailgun from attempting to deliver temporary failed emails?

Tags: mailgun

I am very new to Mailgun and the whole transactional mailing routine so I apologize if my question is not worded properly. While testing I sent an email to `bar@example.com`. I just wanted to see what happens. I received a temporary fail, but then I kept receiving them again and again because Mailgun automatically attempts to re-deliver until the hard fail:

[image]

Say, I figured out what was wrong and I want to stop it from doing so. Is there a way to configure this for all emails or a single email address?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it, you need to contact Mailgun support with the required details and they will kill the email in the queue. Anyways Mailgun tries a maximum 8 attempts after that it will automatically get dropped from the queue with a permanent reason.